# A disclosure indicator/chevron without List

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm using `LazyVStack` to display a few "rows." I don't use `List` because the UI is very much customized. To name a few things, there are a custom color as a background, custom paddings, a distance between rows, and a custom corner radius of each row:

[image]

I need to add a standard disclosure indicator (a grey chevron icon on the trailing side of each row.) `NavigationLink` in this case (without a `List`) doesn't seem to add the chevron. Is there any other way to add it?

And I mean the system icon, of course. I'm aware that I could add a custom image or an SF Symbol and tweak it to nearly match the system icon, but I want it to be system-controlled.

Any piece of advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would really recommend just using the appropriate SF symbol. If Apple somehow decides to change the design of their disclosure indicators, I'm quite sure the SF symbol would change too. Even if that is not the case, there is nothing wrong, arguably, for your custom list-like view to have a different-looking disclosure indicator. It won't look out of place, because it's your custom view, and doesn't resemble the lists that appear in other parts of iOS.

That said, you could try abusing `DisclosureGroup`, which has a "built-in" disclosure indicator.

The idea is to make an empty `DisclosureGroup`, and give `isExpanded` a constant `Binding` value of `false`. In the binding's setter, you can check if it is being set to `true` (i.e. when the user taps on the disclosure group). Do your programmatic navigation there.

```
func constant<T>(_ const: T, onSet: @escaping (T) -> Void) -> Binding<T> {
    Binding(get: { const }, set: { value, _ in
        onSet(value)
    })
}

struct ContentView: View{
    
    var body: some View {
        Color.yellow.overlay(alignment: .center) {
            VStack(spacing: 16) {
                DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: constant(false) {
                    if $0 {
                        // do your navigation here
                    }
                }) { } // empty disclosure group
                label: {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Title").bold()
                        Text("Details here...")
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                .background(.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .tint(.black)
                
                // other rows go here...
            }
            .padding(20)
            
        }
    }
}
```

---

Another idea is to use a `UITableViewCell` with a `.disclosureIndicator` accessory type. This is also quite hacky. You'd need to make a `UIViewRepresentable` SwiftUI view, and inside that, you'd also need to add a `UIHostingController` if you want the cell's contents to be written in SwiftUI.

A simple implementation would be:

```
struct Cell<Content: View>: UIViewRepresentable {
    @MainActor
    class Coordinator {
        let hostingVC: UIHostingController<Content>
        
        init(hostingVC: UIHostingController<Content>) {
            self.hostingVC = hostingVC
        }
    }
    
    let content: () -> Content
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITableViewCell, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(frame: .zero)
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        cell.backgroundColor = .white
        var contentView = context.coordinator.hostingVC.view!
        contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        cell.contentView.addSubview(contentView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.topAnchor),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.bottomAnchor),
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.leadingAnchor),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.trailingAnchor),
        ])
        return cell
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(hostingVC: UIHostingController(rootView: content()))
    }
    
    func sizeThatFits(_ proposal: ProposedViewSize, uiView: UITableViewCell, context: Context) -> CGSize? {
        uiView.contentView.frame.size
    }
}
```

```
Cell {
    VStack {
        Text("Title").bold()
        Text("Details here...")
    }
}
.cornerRadius(10)
```

Now you can detect taps on the cell using e.g. UIKit gesture recognisers, add a callback to let the SwiftUI side know, and then do your navigation in the callback, etc.

Comment: Thank you for all these options. I think I'll go with the "chevron.forward" SF Symbol – it should be the easiest and less hacky.